# Stuck Bottom Sheet in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

My ModalBottomSheet works perfectly the first time I open it, but after hiding it, it becomes unresponsive and blocks all other UI interactions.

```
Button(
    onClick = {
        showBottomSheet = true
    }
) {
    Text(text = "Done")
}

if (showBottomSheet) StyleBottomSheet()
```

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun StyleBottomSheet() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
    var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = {
            showBottomSheet = false
        },
        sheetState = sheetState
    ) {
        // Sheet content
        Button(onClick = {
            scope.launch { sheetState.hide() }.invokeOnCompletion {
                if (!sheetState.isVisible) {
                    showBottomSheet = false
                }
            }
        }) {
            Text("Hide bottom sheet")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue lies in how you handle the state of the bottom sheet. The `showBottomSheet` variable is being used both at the outer and inner level, which might be causing conflicts. Let's simplify the logic and handle the bottom sheet state more consistently.

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
   var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Button(
    onClick = {
        showBottomSheet = true
    }
) {
    Text(text = "Open Bottom Sheet")
}

if (showBottomSheet) {
    StyleBottomSheet(
        onDismiss = {
            showBottomSheet = false
        }
    )
  }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun StyleBottomSheet(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()

    ModalBottomSheet(
        sheetState = sheetState,
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss
    ) {
        // Sheet content
        Button(
            onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    sheetState.hide()
                }
            }
        ) {
            Text("Hide bottom sheet")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dhruvl its works. I also handle same like that